# Why does Dataflow not allow the download of a certain metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I was running a test job on Google dataflow, and I wanted to download the metrics for it afterwards. I can view the metrics in the job metric section of the job, but it doesn't let me download it as a CSV. (It lets me download a PNG only) Some jobs allow for that which is why I am confused. Is there a way I can enable the metric download option on every job?

Comment: Do you mean some datablow jobs allow you to download the CSV data and other not? That's strange. Is the job duration the same (it might be related to a volume of data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 versions of the job metrics section. It occurs to me that only the plots in the newer one (with a button "GO BACK TO CLASSIC METRICS") allow you to download as CSV when you click and expand the three-dots menu.

[image]

You can always "View in Metrics Explorer", do some analysis there and [read metric data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#timeseries-list-basic) programmatically. More details about how to export cloud monitoring data can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export).